# setting up github for an existing Rstudio project

Tags: github, rstudio

Environment:  Win XP, RStudio 0.97.551

I have an existing RStudio project (a book, using knitr) I want to set up to use github for version control.  If it makes any difference, the project is currently stored in a Dropbox folder.  I'm familiar with using git/github on Ubuntu, but not on Windows or with RStudio.

I've read the document Using Version Control with RStudio, 
set up my project to use git for version control, and created an empty github project, but there is something missing, because I can't find a way to push / commit to the github repo.

Under Project - Project options - SVN/Git I see the correct remote repo: git@github.com:friendly/VCDR.git, set up via

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/friendly/VCDR.git
```

In RStudio, I tried to use the Shell to execute

```
git push -u origin master
```

but I get

```
Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I did setup a public/private key pair through some RStudio menu
option, and also used

```
git config --global user.name 'Michael Friendly'
git config --global user.email 'friendly@yorku.ca'
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: Did you upload the public key to github?

Comment: This was the missing step, because I already had uploaded a public key to github on one computer, but not from the one I was working on at the time.  In terms of working with git/github and RStudio, I've found that it is easier to work with git from the shell or Github for Windos than the RStudio menus.

Comment: You should turn that into an answer and accept it.